# Regex expression to get specific value output

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with splitting a string to a expected value using regex.

Example string > `AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances`

Output I expect:

```
data = {"service": "AWS/Compute/EC2", "type": "AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances"}
```

Comment: What is the logic in which you determine the service/type. Simple to answer the question, however without understanding your logic it may not work in other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is to simply remove the final element in your string, determined by `/`, you would be best of splitting the string and not using `regex` here.

```
{'service': '/'.join(string.split('/')[:-1]), 'type': string}

#{'service': 'AWS/Compute/EC2', 'type': 'AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances'}
```

It can be done with `regex`, however there is no need if its so simple to achieve with other methods.

```
import re

{'service': re.match(r'.*(?=\/)', string).group(), 'type': string}

#{'service': 'AWS/Compute/EC2', 'type': 'AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want merely to get everything before last `/` and there is always at least one `/`, then `rstrip` should suffice

```
txt = "AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances"
service = txt.rsplit("/", 1)[0]
print(service)
```

output:

```
AWS/Compute/EC2
```

1 is for limiting number of splits to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because the 'AWS/Compute/EC2' part of the provided string is common, it's best to choose the delimiter based on the string you want to strip. You can use `re.split` to split the string to the delimeter.

```
example_string = 'AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances'
delimiter = '/Instances'
data = {'service': re.split(delimiter, example_string)[0],
        'type': example_string}
print(data)
#{'service': 'AWS/Compute/EC2', 'type': 'AWS/Compute/EC2/Instances'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.